# Is there anything special about the strange shaped rocks?

Tags: candy-box-2

In the cave, what's the deal with the strange shaped rocks? At first I thought it was coded directions:

> Up, up left

but that didn't seem to work. Do they do/mean anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a treasure map

Hint 1:

> It depicts 2 trees and a bit of landmass

Hint 2:

> You found something nearby

Answer:

Click where the red circle is: here https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6yqT.png

Reward:

> 3 Chocolate bars

Comment: -1, circle not hand-drawn.

Comment: @fredley - just for you http://i.imgur.com/crIK7ub.png

Comment: NOTE: This hidden treasure seems to only be accessible after seeing these rocks.